# Add syntax highlighting for Django templates (already supported by highlight.js)

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Django questions are pretty common on Stack Overflow. Many of them use Django templates. Django is [supported by highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) but [isn't supported by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). This isn't necessary, but would be very nice to have. Example:

```html
{% if articles|length %}
{% for article in articles %}

{% custom %}

{# Striped table #}
<tr class="{% cycle odd,even %}">
  <td>{{ article|default:"Hi... " }}</td>
  <td {% if article.today %}class="today"{% endif %}>
    Published on {{ article.date }}
  </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Having it available sounds useful, but due to a [bug in the implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354793), it probably shouldn't be added as a "Code Language" for any tag (not Django), because having multiple tags associated with a highlight language on a single question will result in the highlighter guessing a random language from all of the loaded languages. There are many django/python questions, so that'd be a real concern. It could only be used with deliberate notation: `\`\`\`django`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree. However, I think maybe it should be added as a code language for django-templates, because most of the questions there are about the template engine.

Comment: Of the 18.4k questions with django-templates, there are 6.1k questions also with python, so that's 6.1k questions or so whose auto-highlighting would break

Comment: @CertainPerformance All right

Comment: @CertainPerformance Even if it could only be used with deliberate notation `\`\`\`django`, I think that would already be a great improvement.